# How to call Soap/mtom web service asynchronously from C# winform

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, async-await, mtom

I am attempting to call/push a semi-large tiff and a Gal file to a java webservice.
The platform is Visual Studio 2013, C# windows forms application.

I am pointing to the WSDL file and "The Platform" is generating a service reference class for me. 
This is all very abstracted from me, which is a good thing as I am a relative newbie to this arena.
I left the "Generate Task based Code" checked and I get an addSample and addSampleAsync method.

I populate the class fields and push the code up.

The addSample code works fine but blocks the UI.

The async code, addSampleAsync, also works, bit is slower and is not completely asynchronous.
addSampleAsync locks the UI for about half of the processing time and the function call to fncTestUpload does not return for that same period of time.

```
    //Dimensioned at class level
    //private static addSamplePortClient Service = new addSamplePortClient();
    //private static addSampleResponse Myresult = new addSampleResponse(); 

    //ThisRequest is the WSDL modeled class object.

    //This code works, but is slow, 30 seconds on wifi
    ResponseType Myresult = Service.addSample(ThisRequest.Request);
    MessageBox.Show(Myresult.Message + Myresult.Code);


    //This code locks up the UI for about 15 - 20 seconds then takes another 15 to display the messagebox
    fncTestUpload(ThisRequest);       

    async void fncTestUpload(addSampleRequest SentRequest)
        {
            Myresult = await Service.addSampleAsync(SentRequest.Request);
            MessageBox.Show(Myresult.Response.Message + " - " + Myresult.Response.Code);
        }
```

I made the response object a class level variable in hopes of doing something with it in the function that calls fncTestUpload, which it thought would return immediately when calling an Async function. It does not return until after 15 seconds.??

I have spent several hours googling this and have not found any answers as to why the addSampleAsync is not working as advertised.

Microsoft's tutorials may as well be written in Dilbert's Elbonian. I can't follow them and don't find them helpful, so please don't direct me to one.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 0):

When you use the 'await' keyword in your method you are saying "Ok, you go ahead and do work, I will **return to my caller**, let me know when you're done".

So the 15 seconds of waiting is the time it takes your service to process the request, then invoking the state machine generated by the async method to return to the method after the previously awaited method has finished. That is the normal behavior for await.

About the MessageBox that is taking 15 seconds, it could be that the Response property is lazyloading and actually trying to load the code / message for the first time wheb you access those properties.